# New to ruby and trying to fix the error from rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hi I need to know how to do the following

rspec code:

```
2) WebServer::Htaccess#authorized? for valid-user with valid credentials returns true
 Failure/Error: expect(htaccess_valid_user.authorized?(encrypted_string)).to be_true
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments calling `authorized?` (1 for 0)
 # ./spec/lib/config/htaccess_spec.rb:82:in `(root)'
 # ./spec/lib/config/htaccess_spec.rb:44:in `stub_htpwd_file'
 # ./spec/lib/config/htaccess_spec.rb:41:in `stub_htpwd_file'
 # ./spec/lib/config/htaccess_spec.rb:40:in `stub_htpwd_file'
 # ./spec/lib/config/htaccess_spec.rb:81:in `(root)'
```

Here is the spec.rb file

```
let(:htaccess_valid_user) { WebServer::Htaccess.new(valid_user_content) }
let(:htaccess_user) { WebServer::Htaccess.new(user_content) }

describe '#authorized?' do
context 'for valid-user' do
  context 'with valid credentials' do
    it 'returns true' do
      stub_htpwd_file do
        expect(htaccess_valid_user.authorized?(encrypted_string)).to be_true
      end
    end
  end

  context 'with invalid credentials' do
    it 'returns false' do
      stub_htpwd_file do
        expect(htaccess_valid_user.authorized?(encrypted_string('bad user'))).not_to be_nil
        expect(htaccess_valid_user.authorized?(encrypted_string('bad user'))).to be_false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am new to ruby TDD, and all I have in my file right now is

```
def authorized? 



end
```

I am fluent in Node.js but this is completely new to me.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there in the error message.

```
ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments calling `authorized?` (1 for 0)
```

You've passed arguments to the `authorized?` method.

```
expect(htaccess_valid_user.authorized?(encrypted_string)).to be_true
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But `authorized?` takes no arguments.

```
def authorized?
end
```

Unlike Javascript, Ruby will check you passed in the right number of arguments. If you specify no argument list, the default is to enforce taking no arguments. [Add some](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Method_Definitions).

```
def authorized?(authorization)
end
```